# What is this aircraft (Le Bourget airshow 1965)

Tags: aircraft-identification

Approximately 31 seconds into this video of a [walkaround of the 1965 Paris airshow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SzmQXQoWylU), there's a curious aircraft shown next to a Navy F-4.

[image: unknown aircraft 1965]

The question is - what is it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a [Nord 500 Cadet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nord_Aviation_N_500_Cadet). From Wikipedia:

> A model kit presenting the concept was first shown at the Paris Air
>   Show at Le Bourget in 1965. The aircraft was driven by two ducted
>   fans, with three blades per fan, mounted on short wings that were able
>   to pivot between providing vertical and horizontal thrust.
>
> Two prototypes were constructed, one making its first (tethered)
>   flight in July 1968.

This early VTOL concept aircraft was designed by [Nord Aviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nord_Aviation) (formely [Potez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potez)), the French manufacturer. They were known for their military [Transall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-160_Transall) and [Noratlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nord_Noratlas) seen everywhere in Western Europe in the 60s.

This aircraft is similar to [CL-84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadair_CL-84) and [XC-142](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTV_XC-142) designed at the same period. The only one to have flown:

[image]
<sup>([Source](https://www.aviationsmilitaires.net/v2/base/view/Model/1861.html))</sup>

[image]
<sup>([Source](http://www.diseno-art.com/encyclopedia/strange_vehicles/nord_500_cadet.html))</sup>

- Powered by Allison T63 (aka [Model 250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allison_Model_250)) turboshaft, 316 hp.
- Maximum speed: 350 km/h.
- Ceiling 4,101 ft.

The prototype used for static demonstration:

[image]
<sup>([Source](https://www.klassiker-der-luftfahrt.de/geschichte/flugzeuge/nord-500-vtol-experimentalflugzeug/601630#1))</sup>

---

Bonus: Trying to fly the prototype on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pghVJ2WkBBM).

A quite funny video I may say. With nearly all the attributes of my fellow countrymen of this era: beret, cigarette... just missing a baguette under the arm.

Comment: _gets away with stereotyping by being one of "them"_  :)

Comment: And I thought the coléoptère was the most ridiculous plane from Nord...

Comment: "Ceiling 4,101 ft." - What an odd ceiling.  Is that a typo?

Comment: @WayneConrad: French don't use ft in engineering, it's 1,250 m

Comment: @mins Thanks.  It say "ft." in the answer, but I can't change it to "m" because it's too small an edit.

Comment: @WayneConrad: I meant 4101 ft comes from a conversion of 1250 m, the ceiling was translated from original m to usual ft in the answer.

Comment: That makes more sense.  It must have been very power limited with a ceiling so low.